# Why are the structure morphisms treated as monomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, proof-explanation

My question regards the proof that if $P, Q$ are products of a family $\{A_i|i \in I\}$ of objects of a category $\mathcal{C}$, then $P \cong Q$. The proof seems quite trivial and goes as follows:

Let $\pi_i \in Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(P, A_i), \rho_i \in Hom_\mathcal{C}(Q, A_i), i \in I$, be the morphisms of structure of the two products. Applying the definition of product we get $f \in Hom_\mathcal{C}(P, Q), g \in Hom_\mathcal{C}(Q, P)$ such that

$$\rho_i \circ f = \pi_i,\ \ \pi_i \circ g = \rho_i$$

hence $g \circ f \in Hom_\mathcal{C}(P, P)$ satisfies

$$\pi_i \circ (g \circ f) = \rho_i \circ f = \pi_i = \pi_i \circ id_P$$

and hence $g \circ f = id_P$. We can proceed similarly to prove $f \circ g = id_Q$.

What I don't understand is the step that enables one to say

$$\pi_i \circ (g \circ f) = \pi_i \circ id_P \implies g \circ f = id_P$$

For that, didn't the $\pi_i$ have to be monomorphisms? How can I know that they are, in fact, monomorphisms?

I tried building an inverse for $\pi_i$ but didn't manage to do so, as finding an inverse for $\pi_i$ would justify that step...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that the product $P$ satisfies a [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property#Products) with respect to its projections $\pi_i: P \to A_i$, namely that if $X$ is any object with morphisms $x_i: X \to A_i$, then there is a **unique** morphism $x: X \to P$ with $\pi_i \circ x = x_i$.

Now apply this to the case where $X = P$ and $x_i = \pi_i$. Clearly $x = 1_P$ works, but you've shown $x = g \circ f$ also works. Hence by uniqueness, $1_P = g \circ f$.

Notice that we haven't (and can't) assert that the $\pi_i$ are monomorphisms. What's being asserted is that the $\pi_i$ are "family-wise monomorphic", i.e. if $\pi_i \circ x = \pi_i \circ y$ for **all** $i$ then $x = y$.

Comment: The technical term is that the $\pi_i$ are "jointly monomorphic".

Comment: Ah, that's right. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, and @ArnaudD. for the pointer on the more correct nomenclature